# How can I send an email through the UNIX mailx command?

Tags: unix, email, mailx

How can I send an email through the UNIX `mailx` command?

Answer (score 116):

an example

```
$ echo "something" | mailx -s "subject" recipient@somewhere.com
```

to send attachment

```
$ uuencode file file | mailx -s "subject" recipient@somewhere.com
```

and to send attachment AND write the message body

```
$ (echo "something\n" ; uuencode file file) | mailx -s "subject" recipient@somewhere.com
```

Comment: I tried it but it is givinng no response. Neither it is giving some error msg nor sending the mail to myname@gmail.com. Do there is need for any server configuration?

Comment: there is no need for any configuration. Check your internet connection. I have a direct connection to the internet through cable, I don't use proxies or anything so it works on my side.

Comment: You should also check for [error messages](http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/8741-mailx-error.html) in your inbox. I.e. run `mail`.

Comment: Note, however, that `uuencode` is a legacy technology from a bygone millennium which does not produce what we today mean by "attachments".  It basically puts a machine-readable piece of jumble at the end of the message text.  In this day and age, you would be better served by a properly MIME-aware mailer.  Unfortunately, there is no universally supported `mailx` replacement with MIME features, but if you have `mutt`, that's probably the path of least resistance.

Comment: @user269484 Gmail doesn't accept email from unauthorised IP addresses. Read https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10336

Answer (score 37):

Here you are :

```
echo "Body" | mailx -r "FROM_EMAIL" -s "SUBJECT" "To_EMAIL"
```

PS. Body and subject should be kept within double quotes.
Remove quotes from `FROM_EMAIL` and `To_EMAIL` while substituting email addresses.

Comment: On Mac you will receive an error from the mailx command if you use -r


mailx: illegal option -- r
Usage: mailx [-EiInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] [-F] to-addr ...
       mailx [-EHiInNv] [-F] -f [name]
       mailx [-EHiInNv] [-F] [-u user]
       mailx -e [-f name]
       mailx -H

Comment: you could do -S from=a@b.com

Answer (score 8):

```
mailx -s "subjec_of_mail" abc@domail.com < file_name
```

through `mailx` utility we can send a file from `unix` to `mail server`. 
here in above code we can see
first parameter is `-s "subject of mail"`
the second parameter is `mail ID` and the last parameter is name of file which we want to attach

Comment: This doesn't attach the file, it puts the content of the file into the body

Comment: mailx: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status

Answer (score 6):

Its faster with MUTT command

```
echo "Body Of the Email"  | mutt -a "File_Attachment.csv" -s "Daily Report for $(date)"  -c cc_mail@g.com to_mail@g.com -y
```

1. -c email cc list
2. -s subject list
3. -y to send the mail

Comment: I had to separate attachments with "--" to make it work like this: `echo "" | mutt -s "test" -a ./file -- name@mail.com -y`

Answer (score 6):

```
mail [-s subject] [-c ccaddress] [-b bccaddress] toaddress
```

-c and -b are optional.

-s : Specify subject;if subject contains spaces, use quotes.

-c : Send carbon copies to list of users seperated by comma.

-b : Send blind carbon copies to list of users seperated by comma.

Hope my answer clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 4):

From the man page:

> **Sending mail**
>
> To send a message to one or more people, mailx can be invoked with
>   arguments which are the names of
>   people to whom the mail will be sent. 
>   The user is then expected to type in
>   his message, followed
>   by an ‘control-D’ at the beginning of a line.

In other words, mailx reads the content to send from standard input and can be redirected to like normal. E.g.:

```
ls -l $HOME | mailx -s "The content of my home directory" someone@email.adr
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "Sending emails ..."
NOW=$(date +"%F %H:%M")
echo $NOW  " Running service" >> open_files.log
header=`echo "Service Restarting: " $NOW`


mail -s "$header" abc.xyz@google.com,   \
              cde.mno@yahoo.com, \ < open_files.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a multifunctional function to tackle mail sending with several attachments:

```
enviaremail() {
values=$(echo "$@" | tr -d '\n')
listargs=()
listargs+=($values)
heirloom-mailx $( attachment=""
for (( a = 5; a < ${#listargs[@]}; a++ )); do
attachment=$(echo "-a ${listargs[a]} ")
echo "${attachment}"
done) -v -s "${titulo}" \
-S smtp-use-starttls \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
-S smtp-auth=login \
-S smtp=smtp://$1 \
-S from="${2}" \
-S smtp-auth-user=$3 \
-S smtp-auth-password=$4 \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
$5 < ${cuerpo}
}
```

function call:
enviaremail "smtp.mailserver:port" "from_address" "authuser" "'pass'" "destination" "list of attachments separated by space"

**Note: Remove the double quotes in the call**

In addition please remember to define externally the $titulo (subject) and $cuerpo (body) of the email prior to using the function

Answer (score 1):

**Customizing  FROM address**

```
MESSAGE="SOME MESSAGE"
SUBJECT="SOME SUBJECT"
TOADDR="u@u.com"
FROM="DONOTREPLY"

echo $MESSAGE | mail  -s "$SUBJECT" $TOADDR  -- -f $FROM
```

Comment: An except from man mail:
-f [file]
              Read in the contents of the user's mbox (or the specified file) for processing;  when  mailx  is  quit,  it
              writes  undeleted  messages back to this file.  The string file is handled as described for the folder command below.

Comment: It depends on which version you are using. There are multiple incompatible competing `mail` and `mailx` commands with different options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send more than two person or DL :

```
echo "Message Body" | mailx -s "Message Title" -r sender@someone.com receiver1@someone.com,receiver_dl@.com
```

here:

- -s = subject  or mail title
- -r = sender mail or DL

Comment: Can you please explain why echo is used to pass a message body? If I omit this and execute from MailX, the cursor blinks as if awaiting an input.

Comment: It _is_ awaiting your input.