# How to use mailx to send file as text and add extra text to email body?

Tags: shell, ksh, mailx

How to send some text in email along with the contents of the file, don't want to send file as an attachment? is it possible via mailx command?

```
mailx -s "Email log file" abc@mail.com <$log_file;
```

$log_file contents gets emailed but below doesn't work

```
echo "Comment: log contains last month report" | mailx -s "Email log file" abc@mail.com < $log_file
```

Needed output in email:

```
Comment: Log contains last month report

 <All contents of $LOG_FILE as text>
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282506/how-can-i-send-an-email-through-unix-mailx-command. At least, that link answers the question

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you would do it:

```
echo "Comment: log contains last month report\n $(cat \$log_file)" | mailx -s "Email log file" abc@mail.com
```

The only thing "funny" is you'll have to escape that $ in the filename. You can also add more new lines \n if need be.

Comment: Brilliant sir.  Thank you.

Comment: Embedding the `cat` in the `echo` is weird and inefficient. You want `( echo "Comment blah blah"; cat "$log_file" ) | mailx -s "Email log file" abc@example.net`