# Scripting telnet mailing

Tags: bash, telnet

I want to create a script that will be able to send mail easily with the user choices.

I did this but it does not work

```
mail_sender ()
{
    echo " - FROM : "
    read from
    echo " - TO : "
    read to
    echo " - Subject : "
    read subject
    echo " - Message : "
    read message
    telnet localhost 25
    ehlo triton.itinet.fr
    mail from: $from
    rcpt to: $to
    data
    subject: $subject
    $message
    .
}
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Does it show any error message?

Comment: I think you should learn about [bash here documents](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents).

Comment: Do you know the [mailx command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282506/how-can-i-send-an-email-through-unix-mailx-command)?

Comment: It does not recognized the commands because when I type telnet localhost 25, it's part of a new prompt, so my commands are not entered

Comment: You are trying to pass telnet instructions through a bash script. This is absolutely not how it works. Have a look at `expect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect to `telnet` a *here-document*:

```
mail_sender ()
{
    echo " - FROM : "
    read from
    echo " - TO : "
    read to
    echo " - Subject : "
    read subject
    echo " - Message : "
    read message
    telnet localhost 25 << EOF
ehlo triton.itinet.fr
mail from: $from
rcpt to: $to
data
subject: $subject
$message
.
EOF
}
```

The content of the here-document will be redirected to `telnet`, effectively executing these SMTP commands in the mail server's shell.

It's important that the lines within the here-document don't have any indentation at all (no spaces or tabs at the start of the lines). 
Notice that the indentation looks kind of broken in the way I wrote it above, halfway in `mail_sender`. It has to be this way,
because that's how here-documents work.

You can read more about here-documents and input redirection in `man bash`.

Comment: Should probably use `-r` on `read`, to allow messages that contain literal backslashes; and maybe clear IFS, to allow leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used it for the simplest of testing:

http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/

but it boasts:

> Completely scriptable configuration, with option specification via
>   environment variables, configuration files, and command line

so no need to re-invent the wheel here..