# using mutt or mailx to send an email

Tags: mutt, mailx

I am trying to use the 3rd answer on [How can I send an email through the UNIX mailx command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282506) to send an email.

```
echo "body"  | mutt -s "subject"  example@example.com -y
```

However when I do so, I don't get any email sent to me.

Similarly I also tried mailx which was suggested in another answer to the same question:

```
mailx -s "subjec_of_mail" example@example.com < file_name
```

This also didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I assume you have edited your mailrc and set your smtp server accordingly?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: this should help, https://www.systutorials.com/sending-email-from-mailx-command-in-linux-using-gmails-smtp/